# ALSA. How to change device id programmatically?

Tags: linux, audio, rules, alsa, udev

My java application uses three the same audio devices.
I found this tutorial that how to create relationships between device and pci bus (by udev rules): http://alsa.opensrc.org/Udev#Writing_udev_rules
It's working but I want to create card ID's programmatically from my application without use UDEV rules. For this operation is enough to create id files in directories `/sys/devices/..../card[0-9]/`.
But I can't. I can't change files in `/sys/`. Also, I can't change files in `/proc`. Even if I get root permissions.

Can anybody help me? How can I create file in `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:04.0/sound/card4/` directory for example? Or in `/proc/asound/card4/`?

```
$ sudo nano /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:04.0/sound/card4/id
$ Saving error: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:04.0/sound/card4/id: File exists

$ sudo rm /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:04.0/sound/card4/id
$ rm: can't delete '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:04.0/sound/card0/id': Operation is not permitted
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown on the page you linked to, you can change a card's ID by assigning a new value to the card's `id` property:

```
DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-6/2-6.2/2-6.2:1.0/sound/card?", ATTR{id}="UA1A_A"
DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-6/2-6.3/2-6.3:1.0/sound/card?", ATTR{id}="UA1A_B"
```

That attribute is a file in the card's `sysfs` directory, so you can just write to the `id` file:

```
echo XYZ > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:04.0/sound/card4/id
```

Comment: Yes. If I try to create file from terminal - I get "File is exists" error.
If I try to delete it - I get "Operation not permitted" error.
I execute both of commands with sudo. But root is not permitted. That's question.

Comment: `$ sudo echo XYZ > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:04.0/sound/card4/id
bash: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:04.0/sound/card4/id: Access denied`

Comment: If you use sudo like this then the echo is executed as root but you're still writing to the file with your regular user account. A common way this is done is using `tee`:
`echo XYZ | sudo tee /sys/evices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:04:00.0/0000:05:04.0/sound/card4/id`